# Como desabilitar/habilitar botões de um JFrame conforme opção vinda de outro JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Atualmente tenho dois botões em um `JFrame`: um para salvar e o outro para atualizar. Em outro `JFrame`, eu tenho o de cadastrar e o de editar.

Quando eu clicar no de cadastrar, quero que o de salvar esteja ligado e atualizar desligado, e quando for editar, vice-versa. Sei que tenho que usar os metodos `meuJbutton.setEnabled(true/false)`, mas não sei como e onde formular a condicional para ativar/desativar os botões. Tentei algo como

Os 2 jFrames seguem a seguir:

TelaPrincipal:

```
public class TelaPrincipal extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public int salvar;

        public TelaPrincipal() {
        initComponents();
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        new Cadastro().setVisible(true);
        dispose();
        salvar = 1;
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        new Cadastro().setVisible(true);
        dispose();
        salvar = 0;
    }                       
}
```

Cadastro:

```
public class Cadastro extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    TelaPrincipal t = new TelaPrincipal();

    public Cadastro() {       
        this.setResizable(false);
        initComponents();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        if (t.salvar == 1){
            jButton1.setEnabled(true);
            jButton3.setEnabled(false);}
        else{
            jButton1.setEnabled(false);
            jButton3.setEnabled(true);
        } //no caso o botão 1 sempre está desligado e o 3 ligado não importa o valor de salvar.
    }
```

Mas não deu certo. Estou sem idéias. Estou usando as ferramentas do próprio Netbeans.

Comment: Por favor, acesse o link e forneça um  **[mcve]** para que seja possivel testar o problema.

Comment: Sua abordagem está ruim, você está validando algo numa segunda tela acessando variavel da primeira. Forneça um exemplo conforme acima para que seja possivel sugerir uma abordagem melhor. Outra coisa, evite utilizar mais de um Jframe, prefira sempre utilizar [JDialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html)

Comment: Acabei de editar. E eu entendi o que você quis dizer sobre chamar a váriavel, mas como eu poderia abordar isso de uma melhor forma?

Comment: Pelo que você está dizendo, parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Aqui não escrevemos "resolvido" na questão. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua abordagem não está muito boa, pois além de criar multiplos JFrames(o que na maioria dos casos não é necessário, apenas [`JDialogs`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) já serviria para este caso), você ainda está criando uma instancia completamente nova da tela principal para validar algo definido em outra instancia. A variável `salvar` é  de instância, criando uma novo objeto na classe Cadastro, você não vai consegui recuperar o valor dela.

Uma abordagem melhor é criar constantes publicas, e a partir delas, validar os botoes, passando como argumento para a classe `Cadastro`:

```
public class TelaPrincipal extends javax.swing.JFrame {

     public TelaPrincipal() {
        initComponents();
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        new Cadastro(Cadastro.CADASTRAR).setVisible(true);
        dispose();
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        new Cadastro(Cadastro.EDITAR).setVisible(true);
        dispose();
    }                       
}
```

E na classe Cadastro:

```
 public class Cadastro extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public static final int EDITAR = 0;
    public static final int CADASTRAR = 1;

    public Cadastro(int tipo)  {       
        this.setResizable(false);
        initComponents();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

            jButton1.setEnabled(tipo == CADASTRAR);
            jButton3.setEnabled(tipo == EDITAR);}

        } //no caso o botão 1 sempre está desligado e o 3 ligado não importa o valor de salvar.
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo ensinamento, foi tudo certinho. Não sabia que podia chegar por esse meio, e vou ter em mente sobre os jDialogs que você me disse.